# How to extend Nest's ConfigModule and supply additional options during initialisation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, configuration, nestjs

I would like to create a pre-configured MyConfigModule and reuse it across the application, but I would also like that when importing the module, to allow passing of the `load` [option](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files).

I've started by creating a new MyConfigModule which wraps the Nest's ConfigModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule as NestConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import blogConfig from '@app/blog/blog.config';
import webConfig from '@app/web/web.config';
import apiConfig from '@app/api/api.config';

@Module({
  imports: [NestConfigModule.forRoot({
    cache: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    expandVariables: true,
    load: [blogConfig, webConfig, apiConfig]
  })],
  exports: [NestConfigModule]
})
export class MyConfigModule {}
```

As you can see, I am forced to pass all custom configuration from the entire application (blogConfig, webConfig, apiConfig) inside of this generic module.

Instead, what I would like to do is when I import MyConfigModule in other modules (e.g. BlogModule)  to pass an additional `load` option with the configuration corresponding to the current module.

Here is an example for the BlogModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MyConfigModule } from '@app/config';
import { BlogService } from './blog.service';
import blogConfig from '@app/blog/blog.config';

@Module({
  imports: [MyConfigModule.register({ loads: [blogConfig] })],
  providers: [BlogService],
  exports: [BlogService],
})
export class BlogModule {}
```

I've looked at Dynamic Modules from [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#module-configuration) but in those examples they create a new ConfigService from scratch, not reusing the ConfigService from Nest's ConfigModule.